# Custom sorting in Elasticsearch?

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

How to make sorting like this:

```
->orderByRaw('payed_promo >= ' . $time . ' DESC') 
->orderByRaw('payed_vip >= ' . $time . ' DESC') 
->orderBy('rating->urls->' . $url_1 . '->rating', 'DESC')
```

Here is my sorting from MySQL(Eloquent laravel) how to do this on Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the "sort" parameter.

From official documentation, "show all matching results sorted first by date, then by relevance":

```
   "sort": [
        { "date":   { "order": "desc" }},
        { "_score": { "order": "desc" }}
    ]
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting.html

There is also "boost" parameter, that affects the default results order:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html